# How to make the content fills the space after the sidebar ends in a drupal site?

Tags: nodes

The client I work for won't accept the fact that the sidebar region continues until the footer. If that happens, the client wants the sidebar to stop when the sidebar content is finished, and the main content should fill the space that the sidebar is using now.

How to make the content fill the space after the sidebar ends in a Drupal site?

Comment: Welcome Drupal answers! As you can see, @developer, this is a design question and suits better to Stack Overflow. Even if you do, this question lacks enough detail to write an answer.

Comment: My 2cents about @AyeshK's comment: to me this is clearly a question about Drupal. And a possible solution (or at least work around?) might be using some rather basic Drupal block visibility features (as I described in my answer) ...

Answer (score 1):

This really boils down to what theme your using, and how your content is laid out. But it should be doable with CSS if your theme is laid out correctly. Let's take Bartik for example (one of Drupal's default themes). Simply changing the sidebar-first class to float left and changing the float of the content to none will give you something like this:

[image]

And here's a really basic version the same idea running on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1v24s3w/).

The basic answer of it is, yes, it can be done, but you need to do it through the theme and css. Depending on where blocks are placed, the css already in place on your theme, how you go about doing it might change, but the answer is you need to use css.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question correctly, then as per my understanding i think there is no actual solution for this.

The width of any two elements lying side by side (in this case content block and sidebar block) will be same throughout the length of the blocks. So, content block cannot just take the remaining space, once the length of the sidebar finishes.